# vmc push error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: cloud-foundry

When trying to 'vmc push hello' the sinatra sample app as a test of deployment I get:

```
Time of crash:  
Sun Dec 02 14:11:52 -0800 2012  

NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass  

manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.14/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin.rb:76:in `app_by_tag'  
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.14/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin.rb:81:in `find_apps'  
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.14/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:102  
mothership-0.3.0/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in `instance_exec'  
mothership-0.3.0/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in `invoke'  
mothership-0.3.0/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `instance_exec'  
mothership-0.3.0/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `invoke'  
mothership-0.3.0/lib/mothership/base.rb:50:in `execute'
vmc-0.4.2/lib/vmc/cli.rb:106:in `execute'
mothership-0.3.0/lib/mothership.rb:42:in `start'
vmc-0.4.2/bin/vmc:11
/usr/bin/vmc:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/vmc:19
```

This happens when trying to deploy using vmc to 'api.cloudfoundry.com' and micro cloud using the commands 'vmc push hello' and 'vmc push'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `gem update vmc` fixed the problem for me. Updates to => `manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.17`

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the manifests-vmc-plugin (0.4.14), you can do one of a couple of a few things;

- Use the legacy version of VMC (3.2.23)
- Uninstall VMC 0.4.2 and manifests-vmc-plugin 0.4.14 if you already had vmc 0.4.1 and manifests-vmc-plugin 0.4.13 installed.

If you uninstall all versions of VMC and manifests-vmc-plugin, you can re-install vmc 0.4.1, then uninstall manifests-vmc-plugin 0.4.14 and re-install manifests-vmc-plugin 0.4.13 this should leave with a working version of the "new" vmc as apposed the older legacy version.

Hope that all makes sense. I should also add that this issue will be picked up and hopefully resolved in the next 24hrs.

Comment: Thanks Dan, decided to try and use the legacy version until the fix comes through. In the github docs it says to run `vmc _0.3.23_ -v` to use the stable version. Yet that command doesn't switch versions on my machine. Do I need to create a version file and touch it like the `touch ~/.vmc/use-ng`  command?  I've installed 0.4.2 and 03.2.23 side by side using rvm.

Comment: Not sure about that, if you want to use 0.4.x, you can switch back to 0.4.1. You just need to make sure you rollback manifests-vmc-plugin to 0.4.13 after you install it.

Comment: That said, I did try vmc _0.3.23_ -v and it worked. Although, I think it may be an rbenv thing!

Answer (score 1):

Can you downgrade vmc gem version to the previous one? sudo gem uninstall vmc and to be safe sudo gem install vmc [working_version]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're in the right directory when doing your push.

As a workaround, and to validate that this crash indeed comes from an app detection failure (as the stacktrace seems to imply), you can use `vmc push --path <directory of your app contents>`